# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not initializing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay so i want to retrieve the data from my Database, but my `RecyclerViewAdapter` is not initializing, via debugget it just skips the `setUpAdapter` method.Did i miss something or did i do it wrong? Here is the code of my fragment where the adapter lies and the `ViewHolder` code.

```
public class GadgetFragment extends Fragment {
private ImageView mImage;
private TextView mTitle,mDesc;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GadgetObject, GadgetViewHolder> mAdapter;
private DatabaseReference mReference;
private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<GadgetObject> options;
private Query query;

public GadgetFragment() {
    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Gadgets");
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<GadgetObject>()
            .setQuery(query,GadgetObject.class).build();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gadget_fragment_layout,container,false);
    initScreen(v);
    return v;
}

private void initScreen(View view) {
    mRecycleView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.gadgetRecyclerView);
    mRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    setUpAdapter();
    mRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void setUpAdapter() {
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GadgetObject, GadgetViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public GadgetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                    .inflate(R.layout.gadget_recycler_grid_view,parent,false);
            return new GadgetViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GadgetViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull GadgetObject model) {
            holder.bindGadget(model);
            if(getActivity() != null) {
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(model.getImageUrl()).into(mImage);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Activity is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    };


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

**ViewHolder**:

```
public class GadgetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private TextView mDescription,mTitle;
private ImageView mImage;
private View mView;
private Context ctx;

public GadgetViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ctx = itemView.getContext();
    mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gadgetImageView);
    mTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.gadgetTitle);
    mDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.gadgetDesc);

}

public void bindGadget(GadgetObject object) {

    mTitle.setText(object.getTitle());
    mDescription.setText(object.getDescription());
}
```

}

**This is my db structure from where i want to extract the object from**

[image]

**Code of GadgetObject**

```
public class GadgetObject extends Product {

public GadgetObject(String title, String description, double price,String categoryType, String gender) {
    super(title, description, price,categoryType, gender);
}

public GadgetObject() {
    super();
}

@Override
public String getImageUrl() {
    return super.getImageUrl();
}

@Override
public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    super.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return super.getId();
}

@Override
public String getGender() {
    return super.getGender();
}

@Override
public void setGender(String gender) {
    super.setGender(gender);
}

@Override
public String getTitle() {
    return super.getTitle();
}

@Override
public void setTitle(String title) {
    super.setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
    return super.getDescription();
}

@Override
public void setDescription(String description) {
    super.setDescription(description);
}

@Override
public double getPrice() {
    return super.getPrice();
}

@Override
public void setPrice(double price) {
    super.setPrice(price);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the declarations of `query` and `options` variables inside `onCreateView()` method?

Comment: @AlexMamo just tried it, the debugger gave me a varriable error on the adapter saying ' no such instance field found mAdapter' , and it didn't skip the method.

Comment: That error is not about the code that you just moved. Try to add all the content of those methods in your onCreate in the correct order and try again.

Comment: @AlexMamo same error and now it complains about the `RecyclerViewVarriable` aswell (  No such instance field: 'mRecycleView' ).

Comment: Make it global to be seen in all your activity.

Comment: @AlexMamo okay, and what should i do with the global variables?

Comment: Use it wherever you need in your class. So that error will stop from displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your code from GadgetFragment constructor to setupAdapter method,if that doesn't help you than you should provide more code like your model class and also log errors